# OSRM Contract with multiple input OSM files stalling

Tags: postgis, osmosis, open-source-routing-machine, osmconvert

I received multiple shapefiles for USA states map data split into different groups of states.

Approach - 1: I can't merge multiple shapefiles and merge into a single .osm file because it's exceeding more than the 4GB limit.

Approach - 2: I generated a respective .osm file for each state and then used osmosis/osmconvert to merge all .osm into a single .osm file. I feed that file to osrm-extract and able to generate .osrm file. Next step, Osrm-contract process is taking more than 12 hours for just couple of states. I have enought memory and CPU to process this data. Is it something wrong with the process I am following?

Commands tried :
Actual goal is to start osrm cluster.

For merging, I tried :

```
osmosis --rx Streets_1_filtered.osm --rx Streets_2_filtered.osm --rx Streets_3_filtered.osm --rx Streets_4_filtered.osm --rx Streets_5_filtered.osm --rx Streets_6_filtered.osm --rx Streets_7_filtered.osm --rx Streets_8_filtered.osm --rx Streets_9_filtered.osm --rx Streets_10_filtered.osm --rx Streets_11_filtered.osm --rx Streets_12_filtered.osm --rx Streets_13_filtered.osm --rx Streets_14_filtered.osm --rx Streets_15_filtered.osm --rx Streets_16_filtered.osm --rx Streets_17_filtered.osm --rx Streets_18_filtered.osm --rx Streets_19_filtered.osm --merge --merge --merge --merge --merge --merge --merge --merge --merge --merge --merge --merge --merge --merge --merge --merge --merge --merge --wx Streets_filtered.osm

osmconvert Streets_filtered.osm -o=Streets_filtered.pbf

osrm-extract -p car.lua Streets_filtered.pbf
```

The last line generated some warnings:

> [warn] Turn is a u turn but not turning to the first connected edge of
> the intersection.   Node ID: 19205984, OSM link:
> http://www.openstreetmap.org/?zoom=18&mlat=46.2385&mlon=-116.6238
> [warn] Turn is a u turn but not turning to the first connected edge of
> the intersection.    Node ID: 19205984, OSM link:
> http://www.openstreetmap.org/?zoom=18&mlat=46.2385&mlon=-116.6238
> [warn] Turn is a u turn but not turning to the first connected edge of
> the intersection.    Node ID: 20112910, OSM link:
> http://www.openstreetmap.org/?zoom=18&mlat=43.47379&mlon=-111.96569
> [warn] Turn is a u turn but not turning to the first connected edge of
> the intersection.    Node ID: 20117125, OSM link:
> http://www.openstreetmap.org/?zoom=18&mlat=42.65019&mlon=-112.19086

The next process is taking more time:

```
osrm-contract Streets_filtered.osrm
```

Comment: What is your actual goal? And please share the commands you tried.

Comment: Actual goal is to start osrm cluster.

Comment: Ok! What makes you think that 12+ hours is unreasonably slow? Does the process not utilise your machine? Can you import smaller parts much much faster?

Comment: Osrm-contract output stalls at 80%. It's just for 9 US states data. If I merge same shapefiles using QGIS, it works.

Comment: You mean if you merge all the .osm files into one shapefile you can use osrm-contract on that shapefile just fine? What do you mean by "stall", is your computer still working? Is it writing data? Or does it stop doing anything? How long did you wait at that stage?

Comment: osrm-contract is still running. 

O/p : [info] Input file: /app/data/check_12.osrm
[info] Threads: 8
[info] Reading node weights.
[info] Done reading node weights.
[info] Loading edge-expanded graph representation
[info] merged 782 edges out of 24853134
[info] initializing node priorities... ok.
[info] preprocessing 4778696 (90%) nodes...
[info] .
 10% 
.
 20% 
.
 30% 
.
 40% 
.
 50% 
.
 60% 
.
[renumbered] 70% 
.
 80%

Comment: If I merge all 9 states shapefiles using QGIS into single shapefile and then convert it into single .osm file, it works

Comment: What happens if you merely use 2 shapefiles, does it also stall?

Comment: It doesn't stall with 2 shapefiles

Comment: Can you find the shapefile which causes it to stall? Try more than 2?